# Migrate an application from 2.3.8 to 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-2

any advice about how to migrate an app from rails 2.3.8 to rails 3.1?
Should I go from 2.3.8 to 3.0 and then to 3.1?

Let me know your thoughts...

I'm especially interested in the approach to the Gemfile... and bundler. Any resource link would be welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: There are lots of great [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=27) on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend migrating to the latest version of 2.3 (2.3.14) before doing anything. Once you are on 2.3.14 you should run your tests and check your logs for any warnings and fix them. Once any issues are resolved, go ahead and try upgrading to 3.1.1. I think the largest change from 3.0 to 3.1 was the asset pipeline and you can ignore it while upgrading. As for resources, both [PeepCode](http://peepcode.com/) and [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/) offer great guides for doing exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I know about railscasts and peepcode... I was more interested into the versions progress. So you suggest going directly from 2.3.14 to 3.1 without going through 3.0?